# grok pattern for jmeter

Tags: logstash, grok, logstash-grok

i am trying to parse the below log

> 2015-07-07T17:51:30.091+0530,857,SelectAppointment,Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException,FALSE,8917,20,20,0,1,1,byuiepsperflg01

Now I am unable to parse Non HTTP response code: `java.net.URISyntaxException` in one field. Please help be build the pattern

This is the pattern I'm using

> %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp}\,%{INT:elapsed}\,%{WORD:label}\,%{INT:respons‌ecode}\,%{WORD:responsemessage}\,%{WORD:success}\,%{SPACE:faliusemessage}\,%{INT:‌​bytes}\,%{INT:grpThreads}\,%{INT:allThreads}\,%{INT:Latency}\,%{INT:SampleCount}\‌​,%{INT:ErrorCount}\,%{WORD:Hostname}

Comment: If you post the pattern you're using, we could critique it.  On first glance, separating by commas (perhaps with the csv{} filter) might be a good pattern.

Comment: %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp}\,%{INT:elapsed}\,%{WORD:label}\,%{INT:responsecode}\,%{WORD:responsemessage}\,%{WORD:success}\,%{SPACE:faliusemessage}\,%{INT:bytes}\,%{INT:grpThreads}\,%{INT:allThreads}\,%{INT:Latency}\,%{INT:SampleCount}\,%{INT:ErrorCount}\,%{WORD:Hostname}

Comment: The exception need to go in response code field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you paste your input and pattern into the grok debugger, it says "Compile ERROR".  It might be an [SO problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117563/comment-expansion-oddity), but you had some weird characters in your pattern ("<200c><200b>").

The trick to building custom patterns is to start at the left side and pull one piece off at a time.  With that, you would notice that this partial pattern works:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp},%{INT:elapsed},%{WORD:label}
```

but this one returns "No Matches":

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp},%{INT:elapsed},%{WORD:label},%{INT:respons‌​ecode}
```

because you don't have an integer in that position.

Continue adding fields one at a time until everything you want is matched.

Note that you don't have to escape the commas.